# Lenovo Vibe K5 Note USB connection issue

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lenovo, usb-mass-storage

Whenever I connect my mobile to Laptop I'm not able to view mass Storage option. Instead of that only getting "Lenovo CD" option which includes USBdrivers and other Lenovo softwares. (MTP option is already enabled). Current Android Version: marshmallow 6.0

Comment: I doubt any device shipping with Android 5 or higher still supports USB mass storage. Starting with ICS (Android 4.0), this got *replaced* by MTP.

Answer (score 1):

Ive found 2 ways to solve this problem.

1. Goto C:/Windows/INF and search for wpdmtp.inf & right click and install it.
2. Turn on safe mode in yor phone and then connect it to pc then remove safe mode.